# list the timestamp of the files in "find" command

Tags: find

In bash, if I use `$ find ./ -name "*.sqlite"` , it will list all the sqlite files in current directory. I also want to see the modified time of the files, can anybody give me some help?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can add to `find` the following expression:

```
-printf '%Tc %p\n'
```

to see something like

```
Sun Aug 14 06:29:38 2011 ./.nx/config/host.nxs
```

or `-printf '%TD %TT %p\n'` for

```
08/14/11 06:29:38.2184481010 ./.nx/config/host.nxs
```

or `-printf '%T+ %p\n'` if you have `GNU find`, to see

```
2011-08-14+06:29:38.2184481010 ./.nx/config/host.nxs
```

This last one, if available, is also useful for time sorting purposes.

See manual page of `find`, where it talks about `printf`.

Comment: `-printf` does not work in OS-X. Is there an equivalent to this command that will work for OS-X?

Comment: @WanderingMind: in OS-X I suggest to install [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) that provides many UNIX applications, in particular GNU tools, like GNU find.

Answer (score 36):

A quick hack to get more details about the files found by `find` is to use the `-ls` output option.

```
find ./ -name "*.sqlite" -ls
```

For more precise results [enzotib's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/19149/list-the-timestamp-of-the-files-in-find-command/19151#19151) is spot on.

Comment: I gave an upvote, but this does not show the date properly, so it is difficult to find the "newest" for instance.

Comment: This is the only place where I came to know about -ls option which I was needing badly

Comment: Example output screenshot at https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-list-just-directories-or-directory-names/#attachment_147707

Answer (score 2):

Use below command to get list of files with time stamp.

```
$ find . -type f | xargs ls -l --time-style="+%d-%m-%Y"
```